# How to authenticate front-end (knockout.js app) with Web API (ASP.NET 5 MVC6)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having two web apps (front-end with knockout.js and backend with web api using asp.net 5 with mvc6). I've implemented authentication on the web api and it works fine as long as I'm browsing it locally. Both local password logins and external login with the microsoft account works.

Now, I want to access the web api from the knockout.js frontend and I'm not sure of what to return to the front-end after the ajax call (for the password based authentication) and the external authentication.

My code for `Startup.Configure` is

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.MinimumLevel = LogLevel.Information;
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();

        app.UseCors(policy=>policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin());
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
            options.AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies";
            options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;

        });
        app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = configuration["Auth:Microsoft:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = configuration["Auth:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
            options.AuthenticationScheme = "Microsoft";
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
        });
        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

That in the account controller is

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.email, model.password, model.rememberMe, false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
                return Ok();


            var parsedResult = new FailedSignInResult
            {
                isLockedOut = result.IsLockedOut, isNotAllowed = result.IsNotAllowed, requireTwoFactor = result.RequiresTwoFactor
            };
            return FailWith(parsedResult,"Error authenticating account");
        }
        return FailWith(ModelState, "Model invalid");
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult External(string provider)
    {
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = "/signin-microsoft"
        };
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, props);
    }
```

I've looked at a lot of posts on this and there are some talks on tokens but not sure how it fits in here. Some other posts seem to answer the question for the previous versions on ASP.NET but not Asp.net 5. Any links related this time will be appreciated.

Comment: If your front-end knockoutJS application is pure JavaScript, you will want to consider token based authentication. Search for `OAuth`, `CORS` and you will get what you need.